# Emigrate to Canada

Tags: working-visas, immigration, canada

Can someone without a college degree but with a high-school diploma, some years of specialized work experience (as computer programmer) and a job offer from a reputable IT company, have problems while attempting to emigrate to Canada? I found the requirements for the visa to be very strict, and I'm wondering if the employer sponsorship is sufficient.

The whole process is initiated and handled by the sponsor (the IT company based in Canada, which pays the fee, the travel costs etc). Also a common-law partner will emigrate as well.

(The country of residence of the emigrant is Poland.)

Comment: Is the IT company experienced in handling Canada visa issues?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I think so, it's a company like Amazon, Google or FB. So I guess they have experience on that field.

Answer (score 1):

Immigration applications are never 100% certain until they are actually granted. Do not take any actions that are difficult to undo on the assumption you are moving to Canada until then.

On the other hand, your potential employer would not be spending time and money on the application unless they thought there was a reasonable chance of success.